# CMake: Best method for "subprojecting" files

Tags: cmake

I'm learning/vetting CMake at the moment as I'm thinking of migrating our code to it.  One thing we do a lot of with our current make system is to "subproject" common code files.  For example, we have a lot of shared, generic headers (plus some c/cpp files) which get included in every project we create.  I want to replicate this in CMake but I don't see an easy way of doing it.  To be precise, I want to do something like:

**Parent CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_subdirectory(shared_folder shared_build_folder)

#Next line should somehow add in the files reference in the shared_folder
add_executable([specific files for this project] build_folder)
```

**Child CMakeLists.txt (shared_folder)**

```
#Somehow have a list of files here that get added to the parent project
```

So far I've found various "ways" of doing this, but all seem a little hacky.  I'm coming to the conclusion that this is in fact the way I have to do things and CMake isn't really geared towards this style of development.  For clarity, most of my solutions involve doing something like creating a variable at the parent level which consists of a list of files.  This variable (via some shenanigans) can get "passed" to/from any children, filled in and then when I call add_exectuable I use that variable to add the files.

All my solutions involve quite a few macros/functions and seemingly quite a bit of overhead.  Is this something other people have tried?  Any clues on the best approach for doing this?

Thanks 
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

We were facing the exact same problem and after some time of crying we accepted the CMake-way and it resulted in a better structured project even if it meant to change some parts of our structure.

When using sub-directories the targets are automatically exported throughout the whole project (even in subsequent other add_subdirectory-calls) once the `add_subdirectory`-statement was processed: sub-projects which contain common code are creating libraries.

There is also the `PARENT_SCOPE` which you can use to export variables to parent CMakeLists.txt

For "other" things we simulated the FindPackage-mechanism by including .cmake-files into the main CMakeLists.txt with `include`. In doing so we can provide variables easily, change the `include_directories` and do other fancy things global to the project.

As there are no dependencies between cmake-variables, we don't use cmake to configure the source (features of the project), but only the build (compiler, includes, libraries...). This split was the key element of our build-system-refactoring.